# Is it a Good Practice to move a blog from HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: https, url-rewriting, ranking, migration

I have an e-commerce that is on `https://www.example.com/`, and I have a blog on the same URL, and it is on `http://www.example.com/myblog/`.

Now, according to Google's guidelines, they are giving more preference to a website serving from HTTPS URL.

So, should I move my blog to `https://www.example.com/myblog/`?

But, now here is the catch. My blog has 150 articles so far and out of those 60 are ranking on the first page for a lot of keywords.
 So, if I move my blog from HTTP to HTTPS does that going to affect my rankings in Google?
 And are they going to get back after the HTTPS implementations?

Answer (score 3):

Google deals with HTTPS redirection absolutely fine and maintaining the ranking.

Generally, when you move to HTTPS, you may not notice a ranking drop at all. In some cases even if there will be a drop then it will be a temporary only.

Just ensure to do proper 301 redirect of your entire blog pages from http version to https.

Also, once you move, make sure you create HTTPS version of Google webmaster tools and upload new https version of xml sitemap.

In worse case if you see a drop, don't panic, let the algorithm work in the background for about a week or so.